# html классы и заголовки не реагируют на их описание в css

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

css файл привязан правильно, так как при нажатии "ctrl" + "левая кнопка мыши" он успешно открывается, но в коде элемента браузера и самом сайте изменений нет. Даже с обычными тегами он не связывается.

Содержание html файла:

```
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style">
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="first class">
        SDAIJDFJCV
    </h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Содержание css файла:

```
.first class{
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

Comment: просто .first {} ну или .first.class {}

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что я сначала создал файл, а после этого указал язык, поэтому взаимодействия не работали. Потом я пересоздал файл, сразу указав расширение .css, и все работало нормально.

Answer (score 0):

1. Неправильно задан link, должно быть
2. Надо обращаться к обоим классам, т.е.
   `.first.class{ background-color: blueviolet; }`